# use of static sockaddr_in struct in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, static

I want to implement a base class that would act as interface to send UDP message for derived classes. So, I want to declare "sockaddr_in" as static so that only one copy would be available among derived classes.

If I declare "sockaddr_in" as static then how can I initialize this structure?

Comment: Why? Are they all going to send to the same address? This doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you initialize any other variable.  You just have to qualify it so the compiler can find it:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static sockaddr_in address;
};

sockaddr_in MyClass::address = {0};

void doSomething()
{
    MyClass::address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    MyClass::address.sin_addr.s_addr = ...
    MyClass::address.sin_port = ...
    ...
}
```